# How to use multiple VerificationMode instances for one Mockito.verify?

Tags: mockito

I want to combine `verify(x, timeout(0)).y()` and `verify(x, times(1)).y()` in one call.

Is that possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 5):

Call `verify(x, timeout(0).times(1)).y()`.